# Win11 suddenly plays 'She', cannot find responable Application

Tags: google-chrome, audio, windows-11, virus

My Computer is suddenly playing the song 'She' in an endless loop (54 sec. loop time). This is worrying as I want to be sure that I am not hacked. She could refer to the movie 'She' as well....

I just cannot find the App that is responsible. From System > Sound > Volume Mixer, I found that 1 of the 5 Google Chrome instances is responsible (by setting the slider to 0, sound is muted). However, in TaskManager I only have 4 instances of Chrome running.... 4 seems to be the acurate number as I usually have 4 seperate Chrome instances running (for different tasks that I want my accounts to be kept seperated from). By playing music in any of these 4 instances, I am sure that these 4 are not responsible (In the volume mixer, they respond to the other sliders). Also Chrome usually shows which website plays audio, nothing is shown! So there seems to be a hidden Google Chrome being responsible for this?

Any advice on finding the responsible process would be greatly appreciated!

Also, dont worry about throwing some sysInternal tools at me, but please advice on how to use them to find the source!

Also, from the duration (54 sec.) of the loop it could be a Youtube shorts or tiktok/insta kind of short video playing.

Comment: Check you don't have another virtual desktop with the Chrome window? Also, there should be a Chrome task manager which you can see which chrome processes and/or tabs are open with https://www.lifewire.com/google-chrome-task-manager-4103619

Comment: You can also close all 4 tabs and go to Task Manager, right click the remaining chrome.exe, and "open file location" to see if it's another installation of Chrome that's running. My initial thoughts is perhaps there's some botnet virus that is playing content in order to boost views by using computers to play them in a loop without the user knowing, and this one wasn't programmed  particularly well, but it sounds far-fetched even to me.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
It was a headless selenium chromedriver instance that was running some of my automated test script and something wierd must have happened with it because there was no audio involved in the testing target. When stopping the script, audio stopped playing....

Kind of funny that it played 'She' as the reference to the movie is that it came alife and got it's own consience (and I have many AI stuff running in the background as well).